# How can I programmatically create a new group?

Tags: c, windows

I would like to create a group in Windows, and I've found the next reference but I don't know if I'm on the right path:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374177.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The right way is using a [Net* functions family](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). 
In your case to create a new windows user group you have to use a [NetGroupAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: What difference there is respect to NetLocalGroupAdd?

Comment: @Marc: NetGroupAdd is for creating domain groups.  NetLocalGroupAdd is for creating local groups.